# Reduce Choppy Scrolling in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I know this is kind of a vague question, but does anyone know how to get rid of choppy scrolling on a tableview?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I suggest reading up on the subject but a few main things are:

1. Don't do heavy calculations in your GetCell function (it is calculated several times per second as each row appears.
2. Make sure as many elements in the cell are "opaque" as possible. Read about red/green transparency checking with instruments / simulator.  Transparent areas require compositing which causes a performance hit with the hardware (especially on iPhone/3G).
3. Make sure you are using a constant cell identifier so dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier isn't creating a new cell every time one is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried Apple's suggestions for [Cells and Table-View Performance](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW19) yet?

You might also want to look at the [TableViewSuite](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007318) sample code for different techniques for creating fast scrolling table views.

Answer (score 2):

Try Atebit's fast scrolling table cells:

http://news.atebits.com/post/197580827/fast-scrolling-in-tweetie-with-uitableview

The idea is that instead of a deep hierarchy of subviews you draw everything flat to the content view so that rendering doesn't have to composite lots of transparency.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible problem may be background web calls - if you are using asynchronous calls to servers, try moving them into background threads.  That can really improve UI performance.